# How to create and donwload a file .pfx certificate in angular?

Tags: angular, pfx

I need to download a certificate from the Angular app. I'm consuming a service which responds with this JSON

{
"message": "The following items were found",
"status": 200,
"data": {
"certificate": {
"clientPass": "XXXXX",
"filePath": "name File.pfx",
"utf8content":"0��I���0����\t*�H��"// this is a small snippet of the answer
}
}
}
they recommended me to do it from backend with Nodejs like this, but I don't have access to the backend
https://url2.cl/kDx5s

I have wasted a lot of time searching the internet and I still can't do it, any help is appreciated

Comment: angular isn't designed for that - im sure theres browser based javascript libraries that an help with that.

Comment: @DanielA.White ah ok,  first of all thanks for your comment. How can i do it?
Could it work if I make a file with .pfx extension and in the content add what comes in utf8content? and how could I do this?
You say that there can be libraries in npm do you know any?